# Returning a hash value

Tags: perl

I have .ini file (config file for the database operations):

```
[Section1]
SQL1=select * from <tablename>
SQL2=insert into table <table name>
```

I have written below code to read the each section of .ini file and its working perfect. I have to use below subroutine in my mail file, I want to call it and pass the each value in each section into the hash over there and do the database operations.

below is code:

```
sub Read_INI_files_get_initialData {
    my ( %ini_file, $ini_sect );
    tie %ini_file, 'IniFiles',( -file => "/home/testtool/config/InitialData.ini" );
    for $ini_sect ( keys %ini_file ) {
        %$ini_sect = %{ $ini_file{$ini_sect} };
    }
    print "$Section1{SQL1}\n";  # output prints the 1st SQL1 statement return in .ini file.
    return (\%Section1);   

}
```

When I call this subroutine from main file, I don't get any return value which I could use for further database opration.

Comment: You have a `return` statement before the last `print`, so it will never be reached..

Comment: Thats OK.. but when I am calling the same subroutine in main file, it returns nothing..

Comment: It seems like you are returning a reference to the `%Section1` hash?

Comment: Yeah that must be a copy/paste issue or something like that. You're returning a variable that doesn't exist. You should `use strict` and `use warnings`. It woul dhave told you.

Comment: Yes..I am returning  the reference , is it the best way to do?

Comment: The variable does not exist. A reference is fine, but you never declared a `%Section1`.

Comment: Please add `use strict` and `use warnings` to all code that you write. You are trying to use a hash called `%Section1` which just doesn't exist.

Comment: HI .. I am calling from the .ini file.. I hope you read that .ini file configuration, where  [Section1] is present.. Section1 is lable which and that lable contains so many values like SQL1, SQL2, I want those value

Answer (score 1):

You have a mixup with your variables. Also I'm not sure what you are trying to do. If you only want to read `Section1`, consider this example (which I have **not tested**).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

sub Read_INI_files_get_initialData {
    tie my %ini_file, 'IniFiles',( -file => "/home/testtool/config/InitialData.ini" );

    say "$ini_file{Section1}->{SQL1}";

    # return a hashref
    return { $ini_file{Section1} };

}
```

---

Basically what you did was the following:

> ```
>    for $ini_sect ( keys %ini_file ) {
>         %$ini_sect = %{ $ini_file{$ini_sect} };
>     }
>     print "$Section1{SQL1}\n";  # output prints the 1st SQL1 statement return in .ini file.
>     return (\%Section1);
> ```

The `$ini_sect` is declared above, but then you use it to iterate over the keys. So the first time the `for` is run, it will get a key of `%ini_file`. Now in the loop you asume it is actually a hashref, dereference it and assign another hash (which you dereferenced from a hash ref using the key). There are two issues here.

First, you are overwriting the variable that holds the key. In the next iteration, that value would be gone.

Second, **and more important**, you are trying to dereference a string. That won't work. If you add `use strict` and `use warnings` to you program (as I did above), it will tell you *Can't use string ("Section1") as a HASH ref...*. So there lies another problem.

What it will also tell you is that *Global symbol "%Section1" requires explicit package name* in the return, because you never declared it.

Think about what you want to do in your function. Use as many variables as you need, and give them meaningful names. Do you just want to read the first section of the file? Go ahead, reference it directly.

Do you want to make a copy of the whole thing? Maybe `tie` is not the best option. See [Config::IniFiles](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::IniFiles) how to do it with an OOp interface.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use the tied hash to access the SQL statements specified in your config file. This can be done by using the nested hash structure `$ini_file{SectionName}{VariableName}`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::IniFiles;

my %initialData = Read_INI_files_get_initialData();

print $initialData{Section1}{SQL1} . "\n";  # Prints the Section1 SQL1 statement from .ini file.                         

sub Read_INI_files_get_initialData {
    my %ini_file;
    tie %ini_file, 'Config::IniFiles', ( -file => "InitialData.ini" );
    return %ini_file;
}
```

Comment: Tom your code is not working, it is not printing anything again outside the subroutine .. It prints blank value of this statement : print $ini_file{Section1}{SQL1} . "\n";  but inside the subroutine it is printing the SQL1 statement. In my original code also I was facing the same issue.

Comment: I was calling `$ini_file` in the main script - I've now changed that to `$initialData` - note that if you are using `use strict; use warnings;` (which you should be!) the script should not have run at all.